# Magento 2 : Getting error while saving category from admin

Tags: magento2, admin, category

When I try to save category from admin panel it showing error like something went wrong and when I checked the exception log it showing me below error.

> main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query
>   was: UPDATE `catalog_category_entity` SET `children_count` =
>   children_count+1 WHERE (entity_id IN('1', '2', '1355'))
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\LockWaitException(code: 1205):
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try
>   restarting transaction, query was: UPDATE `catalog_category_entity`
>   SET `children_count` = children_count+1 WHERE (entity_id IN('1', '2',
>   '1355')) at /public/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:555,
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 0): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query
>   was: UPDATE `catalog_category_entity` SET `children_count` =
>   children_count+1 WHERE (entity_id IN('1', '2', '1355')) at
>   /public/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235,
>   PDOException(code: HY000): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock
>   wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction at
>   /public/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"}
>   []

Please let me know if you have face same above issue like this.

What are the necessary steps to fix the above issue?

Please check the process 
[image]

Your help and answers are appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: php version ?????

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there is already some process running and that is holding the table `catalog_category_entity`. you can do so by running `show processlist` from mysql console. If yes then you need to wait for that process to complete or kill that process if that is some unwanted script. If no then you can try increasing the wait timeout for mysql

Comment: Hi @Arif,

I have checked there is no other process are showing, please check my question I have just updated with the image

Comment: Please see this thread `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836623/getting-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-even-though-im`  for help on mysql connection timeout. Most likely the table is in locked state and it needs to be released. you can also try restarting mysql

Answer (score 0):

**In Database Execute This Query**

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120;
```

Comment: Hi @Rk Rathod, I tried with it but not working